# It is possible to hide this dots which is showing if I chose tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

It is possible to hide this dots which is showing if I chose tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle()).
I don't found any result so im asking you guys.[Its iPhone screen where you can see 7 dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAY5Z.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct kafelki: View {
    @State var Index = 0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.red
            VStack{
                TabView(selection: $Index){
                    ForEach(0..<8){ index in
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    }
                    
                }
                .animation(.easeInOut)
                Button(action: {
                    
                    if Index == 7 {
                        Index = 0
                    }
                    else{
                        Index = Index + 1
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Click")
                        .font(.title)
                })
                
            }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        }
    }
    }


struct kafelki_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        kafelki()
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

Comment: .page can now be used instead of PageTabViewStyle. Like this: .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))