# hide indicators for TabView when set vertically

Tags: swiftui, watchos, swiftui-tabview

I am trying to hide the index indicators(dots) for a vertical scroll `TabView`. This seems to work for a horizontal `TabView`, although it does show the index indicators when the view first loads. Maybe this is expected to indicate to the user that the view is in fact a `TabView`. For the vertical `TabView` it always shows the indicators. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72229275/it-is-possible-to-hide-this-dots-which-is-showing-if-i-chose-tabviewstylepageta) seems to only work for horizontal.

My code is below.

```
   var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab)  {
            ViewOne()
                .tag(VerticalTab.viewOne)
            ViewTwo()
                .tag(VerticalTab.viewTwo)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.verticalPage)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
```

Comment: It's because of each application of `.tabViewStyle()` will overwrite the previous setting, so two styles cannot be applied at the same time. Which you can try to put `PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)` at first and `.verticalPage` behind, you will find that `PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)` is used and `.verticalPage` is unused.

Comment: so is it possible to achieve what I want to achieve @JW?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any way to use both types at the same time. I can't 100% confirm it, but I'm 95% sure that since there is no such method now, you may not be able to hide `point` or you need to customize the view. (>_<)